# Problemas ao atualizar objetos relacionado usando Entity Framework e Asp net core 3

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> Olá amigos , espero que todos estejam bem! Estou tentando atualizar duas entidades Utilizando o Entity Framework core 3.0. A entidade Pai "PedidoVM" que possui uma lista de entidades filhas "itensPedidoVM" e eu gostaria de remover a dependência dos objetos filhos quando os mesmos forem removidos no *front-end* e/inserir um novo objeto filho. Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Atualmente eu estou recebendo o objeto do *front-end* na forma de json,

`````
   "idCliente":"1f2d8bdc-dd2c-4a41-ba3e-54213fe19c0d",
   "itensPedidoVM":[ // preciso adicionar e remover itens dessa lista
      {// item existente
         "quantidade":1,
         "preco":20.00,
         "subTotal":20.00,
         "idProduto":"550e9837-f574-47ae-aa9c-d06d4e1d2f85",
         "idPedido":"596094e7-aa8a-4298-b560-af13a8d9270f",
         "id":"1d762af7-e8aa-4303-baf0-45e3d5d47d7b"
      },
     // { item removido
       //  "quantidade":1,
        // "preco":703.78,
         //"subTotal":703.78,
         //"idProduto":"65ee979a-00a6-4acf-adb7-9f934be43ee5",
         //"idPedido":"596094e7-aa8a-4298-b560-af13a8d9270f",
         //"id":"875be370-de86-421e-bbe1-db2ca3754b78"
      //},
      {// item novo adicionado
         "quantidade":3,
         "preco":2052.00,
         "subTotal":6156.00,
         "idProduto":"0104f083-dd99-4fac-970a-6f087554a8ae",
         "idPedido":596094e7-aa8a-4298-b560-af13a8d9270f,
         "id":null
      }


   ],
   "valorTotal":13101.28,
   "dataVenda":"2020-03-23T13:15:17.586685",
   "id":"596094e7-aa8a-4298-b560-af13a8d9270f"
}````

Quando eu tento mandar o objeto completo para que o "EF core" faça o serviço, ele não atualiza os objetos filhos que foram removidos, e não insere um objeto novo, para isso eu tive que criar duas listas uma com dados do banco de dados e outra com dados vindos do front-end, percorrer as duas listas e fazer as comparações de forma manual e executar seus devidos *inserts* e *updates*. Gostaria de saber uma forma mais elegante e mais simples de se fazer isso.
`````

Answer (score 0):

No front-end você mantem a lista de objetos filhos atualizadas mais a lista de filhos já salvas no banco ( ou seja, os objetos filhos obtidos do banco vão ter id não nulo ou id maior que zero, sendo que cada objeto filho tenha um atributo chamado id, caso seja um novo filho, instancie o filho com id = null ou id = 0, e no back-end, na sua camada de serviço você verifique conforme trecho de pseudo código abaixo:

```
InserirItensPedidoVM(List<ItemPedidoVMDto> itensPedidoVMDto){
   // Primeiro remove todos os ItemsPedido que não estão na lista advinda do front-end
   // e que pertença somente ao pedidoId referenciado nos filhos. 
   this.context.Set<ItemPedidoVM>()
   .RemoveAll(item => !itensPedidoVMDto.Any(item.Id) && 
       itensPedidoVMDto.Any(item.PedidoId)
   );

   // Aqui você iria fazer o insert da nova lista
}
```